# Limiting the results by sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a ranking system, and when I pass the player_ID it will return 2 values above and below my player_id. But the problem is if the above or below player rankings are same it's returning all the values, But I need exactly five values.

My Code:

```
 SET @rank = 1, @seq = 1, @last = null;

select ranks.rank , ranks.id, ranks.scores from (   
SELECT *, @rank := if(@last = scores, @rank, @seq) AS rank, @seq := @seq + 1, @last := scores FROM testingleaderboard ORDER BY scores DESC) as ranks JOIN (

  -- find the rank of the user we want similarly
  SELECT @sd:=COUNT(id) rank
  FROM   testingleaderboard JOIN (
    -- our user's highest score
    SELECT MAX(scores) maxscore FROM testingleaderboard WHERE id = 46818
  ) userscore ON testingleaderboard.scores > userscore.maxscore

-- filter for only those who are within given range from our user's rank
) userrank ON ranks.rank BETWEEN  userrank.rank - 2  AND  userrank.rank + 3

-- sort the results
ORDER BY ranks.rank
```

INPUT :

```
id = 46818
```

RECEIVED OUTPUT:

```
"rank"  "id"    "scores"

"426688"    "1032909"   "6138"
"426688"    "1094298"   "6138"
"426688"    "1081638"   "6138"
"426688"    "1016393"   "6138"
"426688"    "1016503"   "6138"
"426688"    "1020950"   "6138"
"426688"    "39479" "6138"
**"426688"  "46818" "6138"**
"426688"    "29181" "6138"
"426688"    "31458" "6138"
"426688"    "33779" "6138"
"426688"    "23640" "6138"
"426688"    "4852"  "6138"
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
"426688"    "1020950"   "6138"
"426688"    "39479" "6138"
**"426688"  "46818" "6138"**
"426688"    "29181" "6138"
"426688"    "31458" "6138"
```

Comment: ...................................... Input?

Comment: describe table schema and sample input and output

Comment: input is the id = 46818, its already in the code.

Comment: add `group by ranks.rank , ranks.id, ranks.scores` before `order by`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry i hope i provided all the details.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
(select tlb.*
 from testingleaderboard tlb
 where tlb.score <= (select tlb2.score from testingleaderboard tlb2 where tlb2.id = @id)
 order by (tlb.id = @id) desc, score desc
 limit 3
) union all
(select tlb.*
 from testingleaderboard tlb
 where tlb.score > (select tlb2.score from testingleaderboard tlb2 where tlb2.id = @id)
 order by score asc
 limit 2
);
```

This returns two rows with a smaller or equal score, the row with the id, and two rows with a larger score.  There are some situations where this might miss rows with equal scores.  It can be tricky to figure out how to handle that situation.

Comment: But where is the ranking in this query?

Comment: This query nearly gives what i need , But kindly check the exact output what i need. That is above  and below my current id,I need ids of the player with same score if its there.

Answer (score -1):

just add limit 5 at the end of your query.

```
query limit 5;
```

e.g. 
      select * from whatever where something order by some limit 5;

Comment: it will just limit the top 5, but that s not my requirement.

Comment: That's not what he wants, he wants to fetch a result from a table, plus the previous 2 rows, plus the next 2 rows, not the first 5 rows, which is what that does.